# iMac - Lower Case Letter "Q" not working in any program

Tags: imac

I have an iMac running OS 10.5.8. The Lower case letter "Q" is not working in any of my programs including TEXTedit.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: maybe try another keyboard?

Comment: Please expand on what you mean by "not working". When you press the "q" key in a text editing box, do you mean that nothing is typed? Are you able to type the capital letter "Q" using shift-q? What about turning on capslock and pressing "q"?

Answer (score 0):

To investigate keyboard problems on the Mac, it may help to activate the on-screen keyboard viewer. Here are some [Instructions at Gigaom.com (Mac 101)](http://gigaom.com/apple/mac-101-get-an-onscreen-keyboard-in-osx/).

Your dialog box may vary slightly, but I think you'll figure it out. If you press a key and it doesn't light up on the keyboard view, I'd say your keyboard is bad.

Answer (score 0):

If after checking the keyboard viewer and all key combinations and the <kbd>Q</kbd> key still does not work, trying hooking the keyboard up to another computer. If it still fails to work its safe to say that the <kbd>Q</kbd> switch has failed. If your iMac is still under warranty try contacting Apple-Care for a replacement keyboard. Other wise its time to go shopping for a new keyboard.